# How can we access APIs of application "A" from Application B. If both are in different tenant of Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0, auth0-lock

we have two different applications. Application A and B. application B wants to access APIs of Application A from backend. How can we authenticate and access APIs of another application without login screen from backend c# code only. Both are in different tenant of Auth0. Identity provider is Auth0.

Answer (score 1):

Application B can get machine-to-machine (a.k.a. M2M) access token from application A's Auth0 tenant e.g.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={{client-id}}&client_secret={{client-secret}}&audience={{audience}}' {{auth0-token-endpoint}}`

FYI., you'll need to create a machine-to-machine application in the Auth0 tenant for application A.